# CRM 2015 Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk: Unexpected results in second CreateQuery call

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2015

Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

```
var ctx = new ServiceContext(...);

var result1 = (from f in ctx.CreateQuery<aEntity>()
               where f.field1 == "x"
               select new { f.Id, f.field2 }).ToList();

var result2 = (from f in ctx.CreateQuery<aEntity>()
               where f.field1 == "x"
               select f.field1).First();
```

result2 returns null! After adding f.field1 to the select clause in the first query result2 returns "x". It looks like a internal columnset is created and used in the context of the second call. Looking at the SQL Server trace of both calls we see the expected select-from queries based on the C# code. The returned second result is not expected. Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: Most likely a bug, their LINQ provider is of very poor quality and can be used for simple queries only. I've found several bugs in SDK v6 - very disappointing. I think the only solution is to create a context per query.

Comment: Smells like it could be a mergeoptions thing.  http://develop1.net/public/post/Do-you-understand-MergeOptions.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me it looks like a caching functionality and it's on the side of CRM because as you mentioned SQL queries were correct. I had the same issue in my applications when tried to make two consecutive queries for the same entity record but selected two different fields, the second request always returned  `NULL`. 
Here are workarounds that I use when work with the `ServiceContext`:

1. Simple one: always retrieve an entity with all fields (without `select` statement) (even if I want it or not)
2. or create a service context with disabled caching

Right now I try to use the `ServiceContext` as less as possible replacing it with `QueryBase` expressions (even if I love to use LINQ).

Comment: It looks like that we have used the ServiceContext in a bad way. We found [this](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/119865) article explaining some more possible options.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind LINQ CRM driver implementation is a subset of SQL only.

Could you try something like this?

```
var result1 = (from f in ctx.CreateQuery<aEntity>()
           where f.field1 == "x"
           select new CustomClass { 
               Id = f.aEntityId,
               Field2 = f.field2 
           }).ToList();
```

You can have complex queries if you want, but you need to know what can be done and what can't be done.

Id property is not always returned by the driver, but the entity's primary key is, which is normally the entity logical name + "Id".

Comment: We are aware of the limitations of the SDK. The very simple second query executed after the first one fails; you did not give an explanation why.

Comment: Try wrapping the queries inside a single using statement. And then trying it using two separate usings. Basically to check if one ServiceContext instance affects the 2nd query.